# How can I tell django to include "ON DELETE CASCADE" into the schema?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I use django (1.6) to create a postgreSQL database that I also access via other connections (currently java and C++). I have two tables that are linked with a foreign key and I want to use a cascading delete. Django simulates this behaviour by default in its own commands:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

and I get the right behaviour if I delete the referenced object in the manage.py shell. (the referencing object is also deleted). But if I dump the sql-schema, I only find this Constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY object_positions
ADD CONSTRAINT object_positions_obj_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (obj_id) REFERENCES 
"Stored_objects"(id)  DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED ;
```

And I am not allowed to delete a row from "Stored_objects" if I have an object_position pointing to it via pgAdmin. I already use this in my models.py:

```
class object_position(models.Model):
class Meta:
  db_table = 'object_positions'
obj_id = models.ForeignKey(Stored_objects,primary_key=True,db_column='obj_id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

although Cascade is the default behaviour.

Is there a way to tell django to add "ON DELETE CASCADE" to the sql-commands?

Comment: you have a foreign key set as the primary key, I believe the reason you can't do that is this, why would you set a foreign key as the primary_key to your table?

Comment: Upfront: this is my first real world database;   If have at most one position for an object in my database. So I can access the position (if there is one) through the foreign key. Is this a bad design? My intuition was not to include any columns that don't add a value to my db so I didn't include an unused id.

Comment: You don't need to add the primary_key for the positions, Django will create a primary key for you automatically (independent from the foreign key), you use foreign keys to create relations.
`myobject = models.ForeignKey(Stored_objects,on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
Also there is no need to define columns as well, Django creates them accordingly to the field name.
Also Class names should be camelcased, don't add other characters (if you want to follow Python Guidelines), avoid object, this is a build in name.

Comment: I know that django creates a key, but I don't need it. Why should I add this row if I won't use it? I create my own names since I started without django and used the names in the c++/java-Connections already.

Comment: If you model serves no other purpose, then move the position into your original model, there is no reason for an extra Table that holds only a reference to a remote model. If you are using this table to hold other information as well, then it should have it's own primary key, not follow the original objects id, the field of the foreign key holds the relation id.

Comment: The majority of the stored_objects don't have an associated object_position, so I assumed it would be a bad design to have a position for every object.